# Running android aab file in Android Studio's virtual device?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to Android so I'm looking at github for examples. With this project, https://github.com/igorwojda/android-showcase I'm unsure how to run it. The readme file says to  `./gradlew :app:bundleDebug` create app bundle. So I have an app.aab file, how do I run that in Android Studio?

I've tried to configure the project to run it in Android but I there aren't modules.
[Configuring app in Android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ucqr.png)

What do I need to do to run this project in Android Studio's virtual devices?

Comment: It is a normal android project. You can build also an apk.

Comment: and how do I run the apk in Android studio?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO and Android development!

You don't run the AAB or APK directly when doing development.
Android Studio compiles the build for you, signs the code (a vital part of the publishing process) with a keystore called `debug.keystore`, and runs the ADB (Android Debug Bridge) to connect to your Emulator/Device... all by opening the project and clicking the `Run` button on the Top Menu!

When you are ready to publish your app, *then* you use the exported AAB or APK and upload that to a distribution center, likely the Google Play Store.

This is a good starting point --> https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/